# Detect Control User Clicked on During Other Controls OnChanged Event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a complex business application where the users want me to validate individual textbox entries.  I am using the OnChanged event to fire the PostBack and do the business rule validation against various other field values.  The issue is that the users type a value in a textbox and then click on a different textbox.  The OnChanged event fires as expected, but I am having difficulty getting which (different) control they clicked on.  I tried adding some Javascript to the OnFocus events in the other controls and saving the control name/ID in a hidden field.  I have a test alert indicating that the hidden field is indeed updating prior to the OnChanged postback, but the hidden field value does not have the updated value in the OnChanged postback.  If I do something to trigger a *second* postback then the hidden field has the value.

I either need to get this method working, or perhaps there is another solution to find the control they clicked on from the other controls OnChanged event.  Please help.

No jquery suggestions please; project does not allow jquery.

Comment: As an experiment, I moved the alert to the javascript that fires  the postback on the OnChanged event,  The hidden field value, as expected, was not there.

Comment: Still working on it, and now I have a solution that kinda-works, but I don't like it,  Instead of OnFocus, I tried OnMouseDown.  This fires before OnChanged, so...ugly...but I may have to go with it if one of you gurus out there can't think of something prettier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `onFocusIn` listener on each TextBox. Then add the ID of the focused TextBox to a HiddenField and read that on PostBack.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" 
   onFocusIn="setFocusedControlValue(this)" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" 
    onFocusIn="setFocusedControlValue(this)" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocusedControlValue(control) {
        document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = control.id;
    }
</script>
```

Code behind

```
protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = HiddenField1.Value;
}
```

However the `TextChanged` event will also trigger a PostBack when clicked anywhere else on the page, and in that case you will not have an ID of the next TextBox .

Comment: Switching to OnFocusIn from OnFocus did not make any difference.  However, switching from OnChange to TextChanged did the trick.  So it looks like OnChange fires before both OnFocusIn and OnFocus, but TextChanged comes after both, which works.  BTW, I understand event fire order can vary among browsers, so this solution may not work for everyone's business app.  The environment here is IE11 running in quirksmode.

Comment: I used FireFox so it probably works with all browsers. If it works in IE it will work in any other browser most of the time.